# Rally API: where can I find DETAILS on EXACTLY what is available?

Tags: rally

I have been tasked with creating an internal app that interfaces the Rally API to do various 'legwork' for a speedier day around the office.

I am frustrated because I cannot find documentation on exactly what is available and how to use it. I am scraping and scraping away on different sites, google, etc just to find stuff like 'hierarchicalrequirement' is actually UserStory. so, it seems to me that Rally really doesn't WANT anyone to use their API... quite frustrating.

Their documentation says things like `toCreate["Workspace"] = ('1234567')`

where it's actually `toCreate["Workspace"] = /workspace/1234567`

I need an enumeration of what's available and what they're actually named.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use one of their SDKs. Their documentation for their REST API can be found here.

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/

Also, here is the link to their app API,

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#

And their lookback API

https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc/#/manual

And if you want documentation to a specific language SDK, you can look at Github.

Comment: The first link helped a bit. However, their names of things don't align with what needs to be passed to their API. Horrible, horrible creation. A 'Feature' is a 'portfolioitem/feature', zero doc on that. A 'Task' is a 'WorkProduct' no docs on that... it's total nonsense. It's like, my son's name is 'John', but we call him 'child/father'... nonsense.